# mamp virtual host only working with no internet connection

Tags: php, macos, mamp

I've setup my own **Virtual Host** using **MAMP (Free)** on my MacBook (*High Sierra 10.13*), and it *semi-works*, in that it'll correctly redirect to the proper `localhost` folder when I have **no internet connection**. However, when I do have a connection, it redirects to a page that says the domain is up for sale.

This is my `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost

127.0.0.1   www.mywebsite.com
::1     www.mywebsite.com
```

& this is my `httpd-vhosts.conf` file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias mywebsite.com
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mywebsite"
</VirtualHost>
```

As far as I'm aware, Apache has been configured correctly, and both the `vhosts` and `hosts` file are correct. So I have no idea as to why they wouldn't be redirecting to my `mywebsite` folder.

All help is appreciated,
Cheers.

Comment: Did you restart your system after making changes to hosts file? If that didn't work you might want to add loopback ip in <virtualHost> tag of mywebsite like `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>`